# Partial correlation and statistical significance

Tags: r, statistical-significance, threshold, partial-correlation

My question is more statistical problem, so I am posting it here. I am writing a function in R to calculate partial correlations and store results in an empty vector. This is a simple version of my code:

```
library(ppcor)

primary_data = floor(runif(50, min=0, max=101))

my_data1 = data.frame(
  A=floor(runif(50, min=0, max=101)),
  B=floor(runif(50, min=0, max=101)),
  C=floor(runif(50, min=0, max=101))
)

my_data2 = data.frame(
  A=floor(runif(50, min=0, max=101)),
  B=floor(runif(50, min=0, max=101)),
  C=floor(runif(50, min=0, max=101))
)

empty_vector=c()

for (i in 1:ncol(my_data1)){
  corU = pcor.test(primary_data, my_data1[i], my_data2[i])
  empty_vector[i] = as.numeric(corU[1])
}
```

Now I would like to plot results. A peace of cake:

```
barplot(empty_vector)
```

I would like to add significance threshold line using `abline(h = threhold)`. Can you please help me out to write a universal equation for significance threshold calculation? I’ve been struggling with this issue for too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for my question was found on the [ResearchGate website](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_formula_to_calculate_the_critical_value_of_correlation).

Simple function to calculate critical p value:

```
critical.r <- function( n, alpha = .05 ) {
  df <- n - 2
  critical.t <- qt( alpha/2, df, lower.tail = F )
  critical.r <- sqrt( (critical.t^2) / ( (critical.t^2) + df ) )
  return( critical.r )
}
```

Final plot for my example:

```
  barplot(empty_vector, ylim=c(0.75,-0.75))
  abline(h = critical.r(nrow(my_data1)), lty = 3)
  abline(h = -critical.r(nrow(my_data1)), lty = 3)
```

Note, the critical *p value* for partial Pearson correlation is the same as for usual Pearson correlation between two variables, without controlling for the third one.